# Python matching

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 3 great lists and I would like to make 1: 1: 1 relationships with them. To be clearer I will show the lists:

```
lstA= [[[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (16, 0)], [(8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (16, 0)], [(11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (16, 0)]], [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (17, 0)], [(8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (17, 0)], [(11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (17, 0)]], [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (18, 0)], [(8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (18, 0)], [(11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (18, 0)]], [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (19, 0)], [(8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (19, 0)], [(11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (19, 0)]]]

lstB= [[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2]]]

lstC= [[[8], [3], [5]], [[8], [3], [5]], [[8], [3], [5]], [[8], [3], [5]]]
```

Each of these lists consists of 4 lists, which at the same time, are composed of 3 lists. I need to match and print each element of a list with the one corresponding to the same position of the other lists:

As an example, the first matched element will be:

[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (16, 0)]), [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2], [8]

The second matched element will be:
[(8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (16, 0)], [1, 1, 1, -1], [3]

Any suggestions to make this?

Comment: Use `zip`... twice.

Comment: you can use `zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use zip, as suggested by Julien and Juanpa in the comments, but then you'd have to flatten lists:

```
for i in range(len(lstA)):
    for elt in zip(lstA[i], lstB[i], lstC[i]):
        print elt
```

Instead, you could also use nested for loops:

```
for i in range(len(lstA)):
    for j in range(len(lstA[i])):
        print lstA[i][j], lstB[i][j], lstC[i][j]
```

For both solutions, if there are instances where the lists have different numbers of elements, you'll run into trouble.